# Recursive JSON Path in Reads of play2 framework

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I am trying to parse a JSon Object with an undisclosed number of objects of type service of which i want to take their names as a recursive path to a object as a List.

```
implicit val collabReads: Reads[Collaborator] = (
  (__ \ "firstname").read[String] and
  (__ \ "lastname").read[String] and
  (__ \ "services").read( 
    (__ \\ "name").lazyRead[list[String])
)(Collaborator)
```

I tried this and other ways but nothing seems to work, as i always have a error on the recursive Path and i couldn't find any example of a Json Reads with a recursive Path anywhere. Is this even supported?

Comment: I don't have enought information to be able to help you. Could yoiu drop the `Collaborator` case class and the JSON representation (if not trivial) please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
implicit val collabReads: Reads[Collaborator] = (
  (__ \ "firstname").read[String] and
  (__ \ "lastname").read[String] and
  (__ \ "services" \\ "name").lazyRead[list[String]]
)(Collaborator)
```

Have you tried this one?